# How to speed up old MacBook Pro15 inch late 2007 with 4GB RAM (2.4 GHz)

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

I am running 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and have about 12GB available on my hard drive with 2.2/2.4 GHz.

I have noted that performance has been getting slow (esp. on startup) and was wondering if there are any obvious ways to improve performance?

I would greatly appreciate your advice! Perhaps this question has been asked before but I could not find it using the search function.

Best,

Hirek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to consider - you'd have to check whether any of these are worth the money on such an old machine though.

- Larger, faster HD, or even an SSD. You don't say how big the existing drive is but those machines came with 120, 160 or 200. In any case, 12GB spare is really not enough for the machine to 'breathe' properly.
- Assuming it's never been done in the life to the machine - defrag, using [iDefrag](http://coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php) (only good to Mavericks, not Yosemite) or similar - bear in mind this may take more than 24h to complete, especially with so little free space.
- Add more RAM - that machine will take 6GB, as a 2GB stick & a 4GB stick. I would always use something like [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com)'s configurator app to be sure you're getting the right thing.

Data Source: [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-15-santa-rosa-specs.html)

Comment: Thanks so much guys @iskra and @Tetsujin! The machine is old but well-kept and just keeps working and working and I hate the idea of throwing something away that still works - bad for the environment! Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Welcome - btw, my own Mac Pro is an 06 model. I upped to 26GB RAM, added a 1TB SSD to the 4 existing HDs & uprated the graphics from its original 8800 to an HD 5770 [of course, all easier to do in a desktop than laptop] but that has kept it good enough for my everyday use, including some heavy-hitting audio & video work. Compared to the price of a new Pro & external RAID, I felt it well worth it.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin But do you think it will accept 6GB of RAM? Crucial says 4 is the upper bound.. About the SSD, do you know if that slot on the left of the older MacBook Pro's is suited for that?

Comment: It does accept 6GB of DDR2-667 RAM. Done many times.
No that slot is not for an SSD. You should replace HDD with SSD. Look at iFixit on how to.

Comment: Actually O/S X defrags on the fly, so unless you already have a defrag tool buying one might not be worthwhile.

Comment: @SteveChambers It does, for sure & I've read all the info on defrag or no defrag on OS X; but I ended up, purely anecdotally, discovering that a 'full' defrag [iDefrag respects the hot zone which might make the difference, idk really] once after each OS update would give some noticeable improvement - & more so if I did it on a machine that had never been done in years. Certainly not in a windows-style once a week regime, though, fully agree.

Comment: Cool, good info, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to answer in one word, pitty StackExchange doesn't let you.
Well replace HDD for an SSD. Any reputable will do.

While you can replace one 2GB RAM module with 4GB one for total of 6GB it will be pricey and will not do as much as an SSD.

And also check if battery is still working because if it is not you are getting only abot 65% of CPU performance.

Comment: Thank you so much @iskra ! Is there a way to find out whether the battery's old age is a drain on the CPU? Like is there some tool I can use to see that?

Comment: First just click on battery indicator on menubar with Optn pressed. What does it say? Then you might check the battery visually: is it bloated or flat? Then there is tools like http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/